# PHP `global` and parameter of the same name?

Tags: php

I am reviewing some PHP code and have come across a function that looks like this:

```
function user_meta_box_cb($post) {
    global $post;
    // Do some stuff with $post
    // ...
}
```

I'm not experienced with PHP but my guess is that this will make the `$post` parameter to the function useless as when `$post` is referred to, the global variable will be used? Is this right?

Comment: This is easy to test: http://codepad.viper-7.com/XigSr2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. There is exists possibility that body of functions contains [func_get_args](http://php.net/func_get_args).

This code might be under refactoring process.

In other cases using this *post* param is useless.